# Verificar integridad de un archivo .tar.gz en Centos 7

Tags: centos, tar

Estoy intentando verificar la integridad de un archivo .tar.gz

Según encontré en algunos blogs, sugieren usar:

tar -xzvf archivo

Pero lo que hace esa instrucción es decomprimir el archivo y en eso se toma mucho tiempo si el archivo es grande.

Existe otra manera de verificar la integridad de un archivo en Centos 7?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: EL que lo produce debería generar un hash MD5 o SHA, con eso puedes comprobarlo al descargarlo

Comment: No confundas integridad con un chequeo del archivo. Integridad se refiere a si es exactamente el mismo archivo que el original (y para ello el comentario de @AlfaBravo es correcto). Chequeo se refiere a si el archivo está completo y podrá ser descomprimido. Para esto último puedes probar con `tar -tzf archivo.tar.gz >/dev/null`